# Trying to execute a SELECT statement in MYSQL but it is not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I believe I have the syntax correct, at least according to my textbook. This is just a piece of the file as the other info is irrelevant to my problem. The table name is user, as well as the column name is user. I don't believe this to be the problem, as other sql statements work. Though it isn't the smartest thing to do I know :) Anyone see an error?

```
try {
$db=new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name",
        $db_user,$db_pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
exit("Error connecting to database: " . $e->getMessage());
}
$user=$_SESSION["user"];

$pickselect = "SELECT game1 FROM user WHERE user='$user' ";
$pickedyet = $db->prepare($pickselect);
$pickedyet->execute();
echo $pickselect;

if ($pickedyet == "0")
{ 
echo '<form method="post" action="makepicks.php">
<h2>Game 1</h2>......'
```

Comment: 1) $pickselect = "SELECT game1 FROM user WHERE user='" . $user "'"; and 2) http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're seemingly using prepared statements, I'd recommend using them to their fullest extent so that you can avoid traditional problems like SQL injection (this is when someone passes malicious SQL code to your application, it's partially avoided by cleansing user inputs and/or using bound prepared statements).

Beyond that, you've got to actually fetch the results of your query in order to display them (assuming that's your goal).  PHP has very strong documentation with good examples.  Here are some links:  [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php);  [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php); [bindParam](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Here is an example:

```
try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name",
                  $db_user, $db_pass);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    exit('Error connecting to database: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$user = $_SESSION['user'];

$pickedyet = $db->prepare('SELECT game1 FROM user WHERE user = :user');
/* Bind the parameter :user using bindParam - no need for quotes */
$pickedyet->bindParam(':user', $user);
$pickedyet->execute();

/* fetchAll used for example, you may want to just fetch one row (see fetch) */
$results = $pickedyet->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/* Dump the $results variable, which should be a multi-dimensional array */

var_dump($results);
```

**EDIT** - I'm also assuming that there is a table called 'user' with a column called 'user' and another column called 'game1' (i.e. that your SQL statement is correct aside from the usage of bound parameters).

Comment: Scratch that, figured it out. fetch() fixed it

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

session_start();

$db_user = 'example';
$db_pass = 'xxxxx';

try
{
    // nothing was wrong here - using braces is better since it remove any confusion as to what the variable name is
    $db=new PDO( "mysql:host={$db_host}dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);
}
catch ( Exception $e ) // catch all exceptions here just in case
{
    exit( "Error connecting to database: " . $e->getMessage() );
}

// this line is unecessary unless you're using it later.
//$user = $_SESSION["user"];


// no need for a new variable here, just send it directly to the prepare method
// $pickselect = '...';
// also, I changed it to a * to get the entire record.
$statement = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user=:user" );

// http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php
$statement->bindValue( ':user', $_SESSION['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
$statement->execute();

// http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
// fetches an object representing the db row.
// PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is another possibility
$userRow = $statement->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

var_dump( $userRow );

echo $userRow->game1;
```

Comment: bindValue is very useful because it greatly reduces injection possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `user=$user` with this `user='$user'`. Please, note the single quotes.

Moreover, you are executing the query `$pickedyet->execute();` but then you do `echo $pickselect;` which is nothing different from the string that contains the query.

Little hints:

1. You've to retrieve the result of the query execution.
2. You're using prepared statement which are very good but you're not **really** using they because you're not doing any binding.

Comment: Still doesn't work, my problem is when I echo $pickselect, it displays it as the string "SELECT game1 FROM user WHERE user='$user'". It doesn't appear to be acting as a sql statement like I want it too! The value of game1 in the database is 0, but it isn't returning that value to make the if statement true.

Comment: +1 but please also explain this guy what a prepared statement actually is and why he should learn what bindParam/bindValue is instead of just moving old mysql statements in PDO prepare/execute

Comment: @narcisradu He does a lot of error. I think it's better to give him some hints instead that explain every error. At least, this is my opinion.

Comment: Even if I don't mind, it's always funny to have a downvote for a correct answer.

Comment: I guess my question would be how would I retrieve the result of the query execution? I want to see what value it is bringing back, since the value it is getting is not making the if statement true.

Comment: If I could upvote I would, I need to have reputation 15 first. I appreciate your help and patience :)

Comment: @CraigSmith Don't mind it. It's not an important thing. You have to study and learn, to became a great programmer ;)

Comment: I also don't understand the downvote but he was probably mad you din't fixed the entire code for him :) Unfortunately they call themselves programmers.

Comment: @narcisradu, it wasn't me that downvoted... I cannot do that yet since I don't have 15 reputation. Just a random person. According to my textbook this should all be working, I don't see where the error is here.

Comment: I don't see where the bindParam would be useful here, I only am asking for 1 record, only 1 time. I only intend for this statement to be used once upon login.

Comment: Oh I think I know, would fetch() be useful here?